# Rerun elastic beanstalk ebextensions script from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have an elastic beanstalk application using ebextensions. 
It works great when the application is deployed for the first time but I want to be able to run the ebextension scripts again without redeploying.
I attempted to re-run the ebextension scripts from the aws cli.

Neither 

`aws elasticbeanstalk restart-app-server
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment`

seem to re-run the ebextensions scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The files under `.ebextensions` are not retained after the deployment, so you'll need to redeploy to run them again. That being said, if you need the functionality outside of the deployment activity, you might want to implement it in another way.